# Service not started via AsyncTask

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have a service that gets started after an AsyncTask is completed. However, when I go to manage running apps on the emulator, it isn't there. Here's my code for the UI thread:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        if (rBoot.isChecked()) {
            registerReceiver(new BootReceiver(), filter);
        }

        if (cb.isChecked())
            sent.putInt("progress", -10);
        else
            sent.putInt("progress", sb.getProgress());

        prog.show();
        new ProgressUpdate().execute(0);

    }

    if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        stopService(i);
    }
}
```

and the AsyncTask:

```
private class ProgressUpdate extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) 31.4);
                progress = i;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (progress == 100) {
                prog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        return "done";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        startService(new Intent(Activity.this, Service.class)
                .putExtra("bun", sent));
    }
}
```

The dialog is shown and then dismissed, but the service never gets started.

Comment: Its hard to tell, but do you have the necessary stuff in the AndroidManifest file?  Try the startService from your onCreate object and see if it will start. Check the atcivity code for errors.  Post the logcat messages.

Comment: Solved! I forgot to define my service in the manifest.

Comment: You can answer yourself, so people will know that…

Comment: Nah, it was an obvious mistake.